# R- Plotly plot dates are out of order

Tags: r, date, plot, plotly

I am making a plotly plot with this data [from 538](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/us-weather-history). The dates are organized but when I produce a plot (dates as x-axis), it starts with October, then November, then July, and then it's finally in order.

This is all I am doing for code right now.

```
plot_ly(weather, x = ~date, y = ~actual_min_temp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before plotting, make sure your date data is converted to a date class. This error can happen when the date data is a character class instead, for example. To convert data to a date class, you can try using one of these:

```
weather <- as.Date(weather$date)

#or

weather <- as.POSIXct(weather$date)
```

Then try plotting again.

Comment: I was trying to do that, but I think I didn't enter it in right. It worked thank you so much!! Spent over 2 days on this oh boy, but thank you!!